# summability and analytic continuation

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Let $d_n=LCM(1,\cdots,n)$. It is well-known that $d_n=e^{\Psi(n)}$ where $\Psi$ est the second Chebyshev function. One knows that $\Psi(x)=\sum_{k\le x}\Lambda(k)$ where $\Lambda$ is the Von Mangold function. One has the equality $\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{\Lambda(k)}{k^s}=\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ for all $s\in\mathbb C$ such that $\Re(s)>1$. But the function $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ can be analytically contiued on $D(0,1)$. So summability methods give the following value for $\sum_{k\ge0}\Lambda(k)=\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}=2\pi$. From this, can we deduce that the function $\sum_{n\ge0}d_nz^n$, which is primary defined on $D(0,e^{-1})$ since $d_n\sim e^{n+o(n)}$, can be continued analytically on $D(0,1)$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A power series can never be holomorphically continued to a disk larger than its disk of convergence and with the same center.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this fact. And what about $\sum_{n\ge0}d_nz^n$ is analytic around $0$ and can be continued analytically on $[-1,0]$ ?